# Let $T,S:V \to V$ be a linear operators such that $T\circ S=T$, $S\circ T=S$ then which of these is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

a) $kerT=kerS$ 
b) $T=S=1$ 
c) $T^2=I$ 
d) $T=S=0$ 
e) $Im(S) = Im(T)$. 

My Solution: 
I was able to prove (a) like this: 
let $v_1 \in kerT$, so $T(v_1)=0$, but $S(T(v_1))=S(v_1)=0$, so $v_1 \in kerS$. so $kerT \subset ker S$. (and same for other direction). 
However, I was not able to disprove the rest of the statements, seems like I'm still weak at finding counter examples for linear transformations. 
I would really appreciate any help in how to disprove the statements b,c,d,e with counter examples, or intuition or anything really. 
Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: $S=T=id_V$ disproves d) and $S=T=0$ disproves b) and c)

Comment: @Desperado Wow thanks :), seems like rule 1 for finding a counter examples here is checking the identity transformation and the zero transformation.

Comment: Take a Hilbert space $H$ and a proper nonzero subspace $M\subseteq H$, and take the projection $P$ on $M$. Then $P^2=P$ and take $S=P=T$. The condition is satisfied. It contradicts $(b),(c),(d)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $T= \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, this should help you for $e)$.

The way I found this was by trying to find an example of matrices $S$ and $T$ that satisfy the equations other than $I$ and $0$. Especially by thinking about the image of basis vectors.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That's not true. Please check your calculations.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I think you miscomputed. $S.T=S$ and $T.S=T$

Comment: Sorry about that. You are right, of course. (+1)